# Android things integration with client app on smartphone

Tags: android, android-things

I develop a device for my purposes which based on Android Things, but I've got a problem with integration with a smartphone application because I want to control it by smartphone.
Maybe someone has solved this problem, what is a better way to integrate it?
Maybe using Firebase Realtime DB or push notifications, because the writing of back-end for this device will be overengineering?

Comment: `because the writing of back-end for this device will be overengineering` now that entirely depends on your project requirements and scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a few different ways:

- Firebase
- NanoHttpd on Android Things + Retrofit on the client
- Nearby

You can see some examples on this repo, under chapter 7: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Android-Things-Quick-Start-Guide

That chapter of the book covers the 3 options in details and goes over explaining the code of the examples.